# Looking in the past for the second time a condition is true in Pinescript v5 TradingView

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

i am searching but can't find how to do this :

suppose that a simple moving average is currently trending up
with barssince() i can find when this up trend started
but i am looking for the last time before this up trend the sma was up trending (before the down trend that ends when the barssince found)

Hope this question is clear ;-)

Thank you for your help

I am searching for a while in different indicators...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ta.valuewhen()` function. It will return the value of a `source` series on the bar where the `condition` was true on the nth most recent occurrence.

For example, you can get the `bar_index` of the previous condition using:

```
ta.valuewhen(longCondition, bar_index, 0)
```

Or the one before that using:

```
ta.valuewhen(longCondition, bar_index, 1)
```

So you can calculate the bars since that using:

```
bar_index - ta.valuewhen(longCondition, bar_index, 1)
```

Comment: thank you very much i will test this asap but the valuewhen( ...,1) seems to be good news ;-)